# unable to install NPM package in visual studio 2013

Tags: node.js, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, npm-install, ntvs

I am trying to install npm packages in Visual Studio 2013 using package manager. When I right click and select install new/missing packages and search for package(eg:ejs) I get [No Result found message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBGLA.png). and I checked the npm install output which I have attached below.

```
Registry url: https://registry.npmjs.org/Path to npm: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

Downloading package cache to C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Node.js Tools\NpmCache\9b301ae0-f271-411c-853b-46a44ae13b54\all_packages.json

Downloading list of packages from https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
Download complete - updating database
Reading 24 bytes from C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Node.js Tools\NpmCache\9b301ae0-f271-411c-853b-46a44ae13b54\all_packages.json (9/7/2017 11:22:27 PM)

Database is corrupt - deleting C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Node.js Tools\NpmCache\packagecache.sqlite. Try refreshing the catalog again. Otherwise restart Visual Studio, and try again.

Deleting 9b301ae0-f271-411c-853b-46a44ae13b54

Current Time: 9/7/2017 11:22:27 PM

Last Refreshed: 9/7/2017 11:14:55 PM

Number of Results: 0
```

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance.